# Add UserControls to TreeView TreeNodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm trying to find an example of how to add `UserControl`s to a custom `TreeNode`.  The only examples I have found show small snippets of code, and are only adding properties to the extended `TreeNode`, not `Control`s.  If anyone has any information, that would be fantastic.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14544/A-TreeView-Control-with-ComboBox-Dropdown-Nodes) is an example for WinForms.  I don't know if it's at all relevant as a model or not.

Answer (score 0):

something like that code:

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeView.Items>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <Button Width="100" Height="20">test</Button>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <Button Width="100" Height="20">test1</Button>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <Button Width="100" Height="20">test2</Button>
            </TreeViewItem>

        </TreeView.Items>
    </TreeView>
```

but you need to replace button to your control